# Angular2 synchronous promise

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-promise, ionic2

In `Ionic 2` the `get` function for accessing `localStorage` returns a promise. The problem with the below code is that the `headers` object gets returned before it has been appended with the `Authorization` key. How could I modify the below function such that the `headers` object is returned only after the promise is resolved.

```
private _createAuthHeaders(): Headers {
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    this.local.get('authToken').then(res=>{
      headers.append('Authorization', res);
    }, err=>{
      headers.append('Authorization', '');
    });
    return headers;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would refactor your code this way:

```
private _createAuthHeaders(): Headers {
  let headers = new Headers({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });
  this.local.get('authToken').then(res=>{
    headers.append('Authorization', res);
    return headers;
  }, err=>{
    headers.append('Authorization', '');
    return headers;
  });
}
```

and you can use this method like this:

```
this._createAuthHeaders().then(headers => {
  // do something like setting the headers on the request
  // and execute it...
});
```

**Edit**

You can leverage promise chaining to make your code cleaner. Here is a sample:

```
this._createAuthHeaders().then(headers => {
  // do something like setting the headers on the request
  // and execute it...
  return this.http.get('some url', { headers: headers }).toPromise();
}).then(result => {
  // handle result
});
```

Comment: Also the return type of the function should be `<Promise>` but I just wanted the function to return the `Headers` object. Since I create a custom `request` object in the caller function, the code gets more cluttered if I have to handle another promise inside it.

Comment: The short answer is: you can't ;-) The longer answer is that you can leverage promise chaining... I updated my answer with a sample of this approach

Comment: For time being I got around this by using the native `window.localStorage.getItem('authToken')` function which returns just the `String` type. But I should stick with the framework and refactor it sometime. Thank you.